# Moving Postgresql database from C drive to D Drive

Tags: postgresql, qgis, data-transfer

I'm a geological consultant who has made a large project in QGIS for a client. Most of my QGIS shapefiles are in a folder on the D drive. I've made a database in Postgresql for some of the data but I am housing it on the C drive. How do I move this database from the C to the D drive without messing up the data? I just want to bring everything together into one folder so I can copy all the data and send it to the client.

Comment: Export the database using `pg_dump -F c -f dumpfile database_name` and send that file to the client, together with the shapefiles.